# WPF DataGrid Row Selection Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, wpfdatagrid

I have one text box, DataGrid and save button which is calling WCF service for 
saving the changed value of the Textbox.Before giving call to wcf service the form (main grid) is disabled and enabled again when wcf call is complete .
I used threading to call wcf service.
Pattern used is MVVM.

My problem is When the form is enabled after completing the wcf service process the Wpf datagrid lost its row selection (means no row is selected in the DataGrid not even default 0).

Any kind of help is appreciated!!!
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try not to disable datagrid, but to do this:

```
datagrid.IsHitTestVisible = false.
```